# How do I stop my robot after it drives forward over a black band and say number 4 out loud?

Tags: python

```
%%sim_magic_preloaded --background Coloured_bands -R
# Program to count the bands aloud

# Start the robot moving
tank_drive.on(SpeedPercent(15), SpeedPercent(15))

# Initial count value
count = 0

# Initial sensor reading
previous_value = colorLeft.reflected_light_intensity_pc

# Create a loop
while True:

    # Check current sensor reading
    current_value = colorLeft.reflected_light_intensity_pc

    # Test when the robot has entered a band
    if previous_value==100 and current_value < 100:
        # When on a new band:
        # - increase the count
        count = count + 1
        # - display the count in the output window
        print(count)
        # - say the count aloud
        say(str(count))

    # Update previous sensor reading
    previous_value = current_value
```

Need some help with this coding,im trying to make to make the robot stop after it goes over the black band which is the forth band and also it doesnt say out loud number 4 once it goes over the black band

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

previous_value = colorLeft.color

tank_drive.on(SpeedPercent(15), SpeedPercent(15))

count = 1

while True:
    current_value = colorLeft.color
    print(current_value)

    if previous_value==6 and current_value != 6:
        print(count)
        say(str(count))

        count += 1

    #Now it should stop at band 4
    if count > 4 and current_value==6:
        time.sleep(1)
        tank_drive.off()
        break

    previous_value = current_value
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work, it just made the robot go over the first band which was red and count the number 1 out loud, then when it went past the green, blue, black and white band it didnt count out loud, but the program needs to be where it counts out loud for the red, green, blue, and black but robot stops after it passses the black band. Also this is done in jupyter notebook

Comment: @ProHAGmaging I think I found the problem with my code it should be fixed now.

Comment: ok so it does stop now and count aloud for the first 3 bands but it stops before the black band, i need it to stop after it drives forward past the black band, and it seems like its not detecting the black band because it doesnt say 4 out load when its past it

Comment: didnt make the difference, i think i forgot to tell you between each of the coloured bands, theres white bands, so it goes like this, white, red,white,green,white,blue,white,black,white. The 4 count is happening way after it goes past the black band, it seems to be detecting a white band.

Comment: i dont know if i can send a link to what im seeing but ill try https://ibb.co/VgHQHrQ

Comment: if theres any where else i can message you, it would be quicker to try tell you what im trying to do

Comment: @ProHAGaming I think that the problem is with previous_value==100 if the white bands are not perfectly white it will treat it as a band.

Comment: I only have gmail as another way of messaging.

Comment: @ProHAGaming Can you also take a video of the robot.

Comment: whats your gmail, ill be able to send you images on there easier

Comment: got it, you can delete it

Comment: messaged you on gmail

Comment: Ok I got it. :)

Comment: @ProHAGaming I replied to your gmail.

Comment: check gmail, i dont know if you seen it